# How to write a query to clean up table for given problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have some database and I need to clean up some data from one table and I would like to do this fairly automatically.

First the schema: there are several tables in this database but I need to specifically clean up only single table.

The table name is `CollectedProducts`:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [date] NOT NULL,
[Time] [time](7) NOT NULL,
[BouquetId] [int] NOT NULL,
[EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductionEnd] [bit] NOT NULL
```

I'm interested in the last column, `ProductionEnd`, which states that if the production has been completed in a given day by particular employee.

The logical constraints on this column are such that there must be at least one row with this column set to 1 at the end of the production on a given day. So it will be basically the last row for employee in a given day.

There can be also other rows set to 1 during the day which states that the employee has a longer break.

It must not be followed or preceded by another row with it's value set to one.

Now given those constraints, I would like to select all the rows with invalid `ProductionEnd` value such that this is not the last row for every (day, employee) pair and I would like to also preserve all the rows with `ProductionEnd` set to 1 which are not the last row but also are not followed by / preceded by another row with this column set to 1 according to the constraints I described above.

How to write such a query?

Comment: You do not give your complete schema, because there is no tablename.  Also what did you try yourself to write this query?

Comment: I was trying with selecting the last row but I'm not sure how to also preserve those "islands" of lone 1's which are not in the last row.

Comment: @kamilwydrzycki . . . Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions. Basically for each day you want rows with `ProductionEnd = 1` and for which other rows exist with a later time and `ProductionEnd = 1`  and no row exists with a later time and `ProductionEnd = 0`.

You could phrase this as:

```
select *
from (
    select
        cp.*,
        sum(ProductionEnd) 
            over(partition by EmployeeId, Date order by Time desc) nbProdEnd,
        sum(case when ProductionEnd = 1 then 0 else 1 end)
            over(partition by EmployeeId, Date order by Time desc) nbNonProdEnd
    from CollectedProducts cp
) t
where nbProdEnd > 1 and nbNonProdEnd = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want date/employee pairs where the last row is not "1", then you can use `first_value()`.  The following gets *all* rows for the employee date:

```
select cp.*
from (select cp.*,
             first_value(productionEnd) over (partition by EmployeeId, Date order by Time desc) as last_productionEnd
      from CollectedProducts cp
     ) cp
where last_productionEnd <> 1;
```

If you just want the last one, you can use:

```
select cp.*
from (select cp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, Date order by Time desc) as seqnum
      from CollectedProducts cp
     ) cp
where seqnum = 1 and last_productionEnd <> 1;
```